# Segmentation fault when using threads on function with large arrays -C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault

I am using threads for the first time and came across a weird segmentation error whenever the called function takes very large arrays.

```
#include <iostream>       
#include <thread>
#include <cmath>

const int dimension = 100000; // Dimension of the array
// Create a simple function of an array
void absolut(double *vec) { 
    double res = 0.; 
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) { 
        res += vec[i] * vec[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::sqrt(res) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // Define arrays
    double p[dimension], v[dimension]; 
    for (int i = 1; i < dimension; i++) { 
        p[i] = 1./double(i);
        v[i] = 1./double(i)/double(i);
    }
    // use multithreading
    std::thread t1(absolut, p);
    std::thread t2(absolut, v); 

    t1.join(); 
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

The program runs fine like this, but if I increase the `dimension` of the arrays by a factor 10, then I get a segmentation fault. Does anybody know why this occurs and how to fix it?

Comment: `2 * 100000 * 8` bytes fit into a common stack, 10 times of that not. Allocate them on the heap, e.g., use `std::vector` or `new` for them.

Comment: stack size is limited. The threads are not that relevant here

Comment: You would encounter the same if you removed the whole threading thing. This is one of the reasons for creating a [mcve] first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double p* = new double[dimension];
double v* = new double[dimension];
```

I think this compiles because of the compiler defined size limits maybe using dynamically allocation.

Comment: Thanks, I used `std::vector` instead, but apparently, everything that is located on the heap is fine.

Comment: @tomtom1-4 -- Go with `std::vector`.  Using `new[]/delete[]` is no longer recommended unless you have a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: OPs code compiles as well. And this may also fail at runtime (although much less likely)